# How to override some remapping in my .vimrc to edit Python properly

Tags: python, vim, ftplugin

I code CSS and Python and for CSS I have the following little time saver

```
inoremap :      :;<Left>
```

This is great until I start coding in Python. Every time I hit `:` I get an unwanted `;`
I should mention that to make editing in Python pleasant with proper indentation I added

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim
```

`python.vim` contains the following

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal textwidth=80
setlocal smarttab
setlocal expandtab
```

What code would I put into `python.vim` to override `inoremap :      :;<Left>` from my `.vimrc` so that when I press `:` all I get is a single `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can put this in your python.vim:
   iunmap :
```

As mentioned by Daan, you can also put the mapping for : in css specific vim file ( for example ~/.vim/syntax/css.vim )

Comment: I liked this method because I use `inoremap <buffer> : :;<Left>` for actually .scss .css .js files. Its nice to define that mapping in one place because of this. `iumap :` worked.

Answer (score 1):

All your filetype-specific settings should go into:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<language>.vim
```

With this setup, your settings are "guaranteed" to be applied, cleanly, *after* any default ftplugin.

Put your Python-specific settings:

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal textwidth=80
setlocal smarttab
setlocal expandtab
```

into this file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
```

and your CSS-specific mapping:

```
inoremap <buffer> : :;<Left>
```

into this file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `:help map-local`.

You could put this in `python.vim`:

```
iunmap <buffer> :
```

Or alternatively, only put the `:` mapping in `css.vim`:

```
inoremap <buffer> : :;<Left>
```

Comment: Whoops, it was supposed to be `iunmap <buffer> :`. But I would recommend the second solution. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with autocommands in your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType css inoremap <silent> <buffer> : :;<Left>
```

This will only take effect when editing a file Vim knows is CSS (`:set ft?` gives you back CSS)

If you're new to autocommands, the [Vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) on autocommands are a recommended read.

Comment: Does not work properly for me - if I set up e.g. autocommands for sh and python filetypes that map keys, and I open a new python file, the python mappings work fine. If I then open a shell script, the mappings change as expected to the `sh` filetype. But then switching back to the python buffer, the `sh` mappings remain active.